# Cómo puedo hacer funcionar mi carousel?

Tags: javascript, html

Tengo un carousel creado y me carga y me muestra la cantidad de imagenes respectivas, pero se supone que se cambiarian automaticamente y no es el caso, ademas al pulsar los botones tampoco cambia, si alguien me ayuda lo agradeceria mucho :)

adjunto imagen del carusel:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si observan, la cantidad es correcta, sale que hay 6 fotos pero los botones para ver las otras no estan funcionando.

Aqui el codigo:

HTML

```
<div id="carrousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <ol class="carousel-indicators" id="indicators">
  </ol>
  <div class="carousel-inner" id="fotos">
  </div>
</div>
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
$.get('api/v1/restaurante/' + id_restaurante + '/restaurante_imagenes', {}, function(returnedData){
    if(returnedData["error"] == false){
        var i = 0;
        returnedData["restaurante_imagenes"].forEach(function(imagenes){

            i++;

            if(i == 0){
                $("#indicators").append("<li data-target='#carrousel' data-slide-to='" + i + "' class='active'></li>");
            }else{
                $("#indicators").append("<li data-target='#carrousel' data-slide-to='" + i + "' class='active'></li>");
            }
            $("#fotos").append("<div class='carousel-item active'><img class='d-block w-100' src=" + imagenes["imagen"] + "></div>");
            $("#carrousel").append("<a class='carousel-control-prev' href='#carrousel' role='button' data-slide='prev'><span class='carousel-control-prev-icon' aria-hidden='true'></span><span class='sr-only'>Previous</span></a><a class='carousel-control-next' href='#carrousel' role='button' data-slide='next'><span class='carousel-control-next-icon' aria-hidden='true'></span><span class='sr-only'>Next</span></a>")
        });
    }
});
```

Gracias de antemano la ayuda :)

Comment: ¿Usas Bootstrap? Si es el caso, asegúrate de instanciar en el orden adecuado los scripts del mismo. Saludos

Comment: Si es de bootstrap, pero segun yo si esta bien pero igual no esta mostrando =/